# Rational numbers in NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, precision-and-accuracy, arbitrary-precision

Is it possible to use `NDSolve` with `Rational` numbers instead of `Real`?
I use all rational numbers for the constants I provide to `NDSolve`, but it always seems to make computations with `Real` numbers.
My question is less about some specific code and more about how NDSolve works, thanks!

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Please add to your post the Mathematica code that you have tried out so far.

Comment: Rational numbers will allow you to set the `WorkingPrecision` to be high, but I believe the computation will always be decimal numbers.

Comment: @Syed My question is less about some specific code and more about how NDSolve works, thanks!

Comment: @BillWatts So there is no way to integrate with rational numbers, then?

Comment: @amzon-ex It is possible to integrate with rational numbers, but we didn't see your equations yet:)

Comment: @AlexTrounev Alright, I'll update the question with some relevant code

Comment: A `Rational` number is exact, and you need an exact solver, such as `DSolve`, to keep results exact. `NDSolve` is an approximate (numerical) solver and uses floating-point rationals (a.k.a. `Real` numbers, or sometimes `Complex`) to approximate the solution. Of course, (binary) floating-point does not represent all rationals, only those whose denominators are powers of 2. But they are rational numbers, technically. You can convert them in the solution to their `Rational` equivalents with `SetPrecision[x, Infinity]`; or `Rationalize[x, 0]` to convert to a rational approximation.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Understood. `DSolve`, however is an analytical solver, right? In case an analytical solution does not exist, `DSolve` wouldn't solve it numerically with `Rational` numbers...

Comment: Yes, that's right. Only `NDSolve` solves diff. eqs. numerically, and it uses only machine floating-point numbers or "bignum," arbitrary-precision numbers.